# How to run an executable program in Fortran and block it's stdout

Tags: windows, fortran

I have an `exe` program and I want to invoke it in my program.

However, the `exe` has too much output in console and the `systemqq` function seems can not block it.

the signal of finishing the `exe` is demanded so I have to wait the termination of the program.

I have the source of `exe` program and considered to change it to a window program instead of a console program, but it is much more complex than doing this in C/C++.

Win32 api `Creating Processes` is also considered, but I have no idea how to use it in `Fortran`.

I am not an expert in `Fortran`. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the executable is a.exe, you can redirect its output to the Windows equivalent of /dev/null using

```
a.exe > nul
```